# Autocompletion does not work in R terminal inside square brackets

Tags: r, autocomplete, terminal

I am using R from the command line and noticed that autocompletion of list names does not work when inside square brackets. Consider this example:

```
myList <- list(firstElement=sample(1:10), secondElement=sample(1:10))
```

Typing out `myList$f` and then pressing *tab* gives `myList$firstElement`

But does not work here (at `myList$s` inside the brackets):

```
myList$firstElement[myList$secondElement > 5]
```

My question is - why it does not work and is there something one can do to make it work?

Comment: What is your OS, R version, and shell (Bash, Zsh, etc...)?

Comment: OS X (had same with zenwalk linux). Current shell is zsh, but I got the same with bash. R version - 3.1.2 (Again had the same with earlier versions). You can't reproduce this?

Comment: I don't have access to an OS X machine at the moment, but on CentOS 7 running R 3.1.2, I get the same behavior you describe. The latest version of RStudio (0.99.441) added this feature (tab completion for `[` and `[[`), so I'm guessing this is not currently available when using R from a console / shell. Given RStudio's adoption though, hopefully it will be added at some point.

Comment: it made my day when RStudio added this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the term inside round brackets seems to work

```
myList$firstElement[(myList$
```

No idea why it doesn't autocomplete without this though.